# How to instantiate generic function from a trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics

I'm having a weird type mismatch error in Scala when I try to define a class that extends a Trait. I define the following trait

```
trait T {
    def f[A,B](x: A): B
}
```

And then I define the following class which implements this trait

```
class A() extends T {
    def f[Unit,Int](x: Unit) = {
        10
    }
}
```

The idea behind this is that I want to guarantee that any class which has the T trait has a function called "f", regardless of the shape of this function (i.e regardless of its type).

The problem comes when I try to execute the above code, and I get the following error

> defined trait T
>       :14: error: type mismatch;
>       found   : scala.Int(10)
>       required: Int

So I don't know how am I supposed to specify the type so as to make this work. I have tried to instantiate f as

```
    def f[Unit,scala.Int(10)](x: Unit) = {
        10
    }
```

But then the compiler complaints that the type name cannot have '.' .
What am I missing?

Comment: When you write `def f[Unit,Int](x: Unit)`, you're declaring a generic method with two type parameters `Unit` and `Int` that shadow the builtin types of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
trait T[A,B] {
  def f(x: A): B
}

class Impl1 extends T[Int, Unit] {
  override def f(x: Int): Unit = println(x)
}

class Impl2 extends T[Unit, Int] {
  override def f(x: Unit): Int = 10
}
```

Comment: I see, this allows to have generic f but the problem is that now Impl1 and Impl2 are of two different types. I mean, I cannot have an object of class Impl1 an another object of class Impl2 in a List that holds elements of type T (i.e I cannot do List[T] = List(new Impl1(), new Impl2())), right?